# Open Source SPDY Proxy

Tags: proxy, spdy

Has anyone developed an open source SPDY proxy?

I can't find one via Google, but I believe the Amazon Silk browser uses one?

Answer (score 8):

I wrote SPDY reverse proxy called [shrpx](http://spdylay.sourceforge.net/package_README.html#shrpx-a-reverse-proxy-for-spdy-https) in C/C++.
It also serves as SSL/SPDY proxy with squid as backend server.

Answer (score 5):

The SPDY proxy has been implemented in jetty:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/spdy-dev/and5OLY4AsI

We've finished the basic documentation which can be found here:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy-configuring-proxy.html

The proxy is now also able to receive SPDY and talk plain HTTP to an upstream server to terminate SPDY on the frontend servers for example.

Answer (score 2):

[Jetty SPDY](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY) does not provide directly a SPDY proxy, but provides both SPDY client and SPDY server functionalities - in Java - that are needed to build a proxy.

We may be working on a SPDY proxy in the next future.